# error while trying to run MPI program with username

Tags: c, multiprocessing, mpi, mpich

When I run program via:

```
myshell$] mpirun --hosts localhost,192.168.1.4 ./a.out
```

the program executes successfully. Now when I try to run:

```
myshell$] mpirun --hosts localhost,myac@192.168.1.4 ./a.out
```

openssh prompts for password. I get:

```
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(433)..............: 
MPID_Init(176).....................: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(70).................: 
MPID_nem_init(286).................: 
MPID_nem_tcp_init(108).............: 
MPID_nem_tcp_get_business_card(354): 
MPID_nem_tcp_init(313).............: gethostbyname failed, myac@192.168.1.4 (errno 1)

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 1
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
[proxy:0:0@myac] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (./pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:886): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:0@myac] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:0@myac] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec@myac] HYDT_bscu_wait_for_completion (./tools/bootstrap/utils/bscu_wait.c:76): one of the processes terminated badly; aborting
[mpiexec@myac] HYDT_bsci_wait_for_completion (./tools/bootstrap/src/bsci_wait.c:23): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@myac] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:217): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@myac] main (./ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:331): process manager error waiting for completion
```

Why am I getting error when I am providing the username?

Comment: You probably have to pass the password no?

Comment: i was prompted for password , and i correctly supplied the same,
otherwise it would have given "permission denied error"

Comment: Can you ssh to `192.168.1.4` using that username without a password. If not, you need to set it up so that you can do that first. MPICH requires passwordless access.

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying a username in your ssh config file (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/) instead of on the mpirun command line.  That way perhaps mpirun would not be confused by the extra username part, which as far as I can see from the documentation it does not support.  But ssh could, behind the scenes, use the username you specify in your ssh config file.  And of course you'll want to set up SSH keys so you don't have to type a password.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe MPICH supports providing usernames in the `--hosts` value on the command line. You should try the host file based method described on the wiki. http://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager#Using_Hydra_on_Machines_with_Different_User_Names

For example:

```
shell$ cat hosts
donner  user=foo
foo     user=bar
shakey  user=bar
terra   user=foo
```